# Is there any way to call the api and save it using useState in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router, react-hooks, react-dom

I am facing some issue while calling api in useEffect and saving it using useState **each time my page is reloaded or visited**.

I am call the api in useEffect and than setting its data using useState in **datas** variable.and using that data to pass some value in element **<Casebox / >**.

When I implemented it for first time, it works absolutely fine, I was getting the data on my screen what i wanted to show,  But when I reloaded the page it throws some error on the screen saying my **datas** variable is undefined.

I am sharing my code and snippet of error i got. Please help me to solve this error.

**Code :-**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Casebox from './casebox';
import StatecaseContainer from './statecaseContainer';

function Home(){

    const [datas, setDatas] = React.useState({});
 
   React.useEffect(function effectFunction() {
       function fetchapi() {
           axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json')
                .then((response) => {
                    setDatas(response.data);
                });
       }
       fetchapi();
   }, []);


    return (
        <div className="container-fluid caseinfocontainer">

            <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 justify-content-center">

                <Casebox 
                    caseId="totalcases" 
                    caseHeading="Infected"
                    caseCount={datas.statewise[0].confirmed}
                />
                <Casebox 
                    caseId="recovered" 
                    caseHeading="Recovered"
                    caseCount="2892223"
                />
                <Casebox 
                    caseId="deaths" 
                    caseHeading="Deaths"
                    caseCount="2892223"
                />
                <Casebox 
                    caseId="vaccinated" 
                    caseHeading="Vaccinated"
                    caseCount="2892223"
                />
        
            </div>

            <StatecaseContainer />

        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

**My Error :-**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuJds.png)

**Note :- I want to call api when the page is visited or reloaded.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fetch method takes some time to complete, so there is a time where  your `datas` state is undefined on initial state. You can simply combat this by adding conditional rendering to check if the `datas` state exist yet.

By adding `datas &&` in front of your div, it will check the state of datas. If `datas` is undefined, it won't show the div, else, it will show.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Casebox from './casebox';
import StatecaseContainer from './statecaseContainer';

function Home(){

    const [datas, setDatas] = React.useState({});
 
   React.useEffect(function effectFunction() {
       function fetchapi() {
           axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json')
                .then((response) => {
                    setDatas(response.data);
                });
       }
       fetchapi();
   }, []);


    return (
        <div className="container-fluid caseinfocontainer">

            {{datas && <div className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 justify-content-center">

                <Casebox 
                    caseId="totalcases" 
                    caseHeading="Infected"
                    caseCount={datas.statewise[0].confirmed}
                />
                <Casebox 
                    caseId="recovered" 
                    caseHeading="Recovered"
                    caseCount="2892223"
                />
                <Casebox 
                    caseId="deaths" 
                    caseHeading="Deaths"
                    caseCount="2892223"
                />
                <Casebox 
                    caseId="vaccinated" 
                    caseHeading="Vaccinated"
                    caseCount="2892223"
                />
        
            </div>}}

            <StatecaseContainer />

        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: I tried you code but it is giving some error 

`SyntaxError: P:\Covid19-tracker-react\client\src\component\home\Home.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (24:20)`

and pointing to **&&** operator you have used

Comment: Adding to this answer, try using more atomic values on the state. The response from that API call is HUGE and you might get some problems handling all that stuff with only one variable.

For example: rename the datas variable to statewise and using that variable only for statewise data.

Comment: **&&** operator is throing errors. how to resolve this please tell.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the new errors?